# Passing data (from html table, only of the rows selected by a checkbox) as array from javascript to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to data from the view to the controller of only the rows that are selected using a checkbox in a html table.
I have this ViewModel, refer below:

```
public class ConsignGroupsViewModel
{
    public int SKU { get; set; }
    public int consignmentid { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string PharmaName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sortable" 
       id="myTable1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
      <th>PO</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  @foreach(var item in Model)
  { 
    @foreach(var grp in item.Take(1))
    {
    <tr>
      <td>@grp.ShortName @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>grp.SKU,"SKUs")</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => grp.PharmaName)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => grp.Supplier)</td>
      <td><input type ="checkbox" name=PO value="@grp.SupplierId" 
                 title="@grp.SupplierId" class="checkbox chk" /></td>
    </tr>
    } 
  }
</table>
```

I have grouped the records and displaying as above in the View.. I want to check the checkbox and on submit button,i have to pass only the values of the selected rows to the View. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet, this will fetch all the selected values seperated by #

```
    var cBoxes = document.getElementsByName('PO');
    var selectedVal = '';
    for(var i=0;i<cBoxes.length;i++){
    var cBox = cBoxes[i]
        if(cBox.checked){
            selectedVal  =selectedVal+cBox.value+'#';
        }
    }
    console.log(selectedVal);
```

Comment: can you pls eloborate. Am not very proficient in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormCollection in your controller and access this value using it.
Let's say your controller action is

public ActionResult Action(FormCollection form)
{
   form["PO"]; //It will give you supplier ids of checked records in comma separated format.
}